# Aligning and setting the spacing of unit with their parameter in table

Tags: tables, spacing, align, bold, units

I want to align and set the spacing between the unit(with their parameter) of 1st-row entry:

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm} | m{1cm}| m{1.4cm} | m{1.4cm} | m{1.4cm} | m{1.75cm}| m{1.5 cm}| m{1.2cm}| } 
    \hline 
    Sample & $E_{img}$ & $ I_{img} $ &$\beta_a $ & $\beta_c$ &  $R_p $ & $ CR  $ & CIE $\%$ \\
    &{(mV)}& ($\muA$ cm^{-2})&(mV/dec) &(mV/dec) & (k\varOmega cm^-2) & $(mm/y)*10^{-3} $ & & 
    \hline  
    Fe & 701.3 & 1.555 & 118.5 & 280.8 & 25.2 & 15.1 & - \\ 
    \hline
    1 mm/s  & 709.88 &  0.164 & 207.7   & 254.8 & 170 & 0.699 & 94.45\\
    \hline
    0.18mm/s    & 751.4 & 0.048 &   239.3 & 172.0 &     590  &0.531 & 95.84\\
    \hline
    0.16mm/s &  760.1 & 0.058 & 113.8 & 189.2 & 511  & 0.643 &  94.97\\
    \hline
    0.14mm/s & 760.9 &  0.004 & 395.2 & 295.6 &     9720 &  0.055 & 39.65\\
    \hline
    0.13mm/s     & 846.9 &  0.311 & 153.4 & 119.2 & 2970 &  0.153 & 39.04\\
    \hline
    0.12mm/s & 826.4     & 0.016 &  97.7 &  277.6 & 609.1 & 0.912 & 94.28\\
    \hline
    0.1mm/s &   725.4 &     0.002 & 126.6 & 120.4 & 7580.0 & 0.0279 &   39.82 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 7):

Although this does not directly answer your question, I suggest the following redesign based on `siunitx` for the units and the alignment of numbers within a column and `booktabs` for horizontal lines with improved spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.2,table-space-text-post=\;\si{\mm\per\second}]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=1.3]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=4.1]
                S[table-format=2.4]
                S[table-format=2.2]@{}} 
    \toprule 
    {Sample} & {$E_{img}$} & {$ I_{img}$} & {$\beta_a$} & {$\beta_c$} &  {$R_p $} & {$ CR  $} & {CIE}  \\
    & {(\si{\milli\volt})}
      & {(\si{\micro\ampere\per\cm\squared})} 
        & {(\si{\milli\volt\per dec})}
          & {(\si{\milli\volt\per dec})} 
            & {(\si{\kilo\ohm\per\cm\squared})} 
              & {(\SI{e-3}{\mm\per y})}  
                & {(\%)} \\
    \midrule  
    {Al bare} & 791.3 & 1.555 & 118.5 & 280.8 & 25.2 & 15.1 & {--} \\     1\;\si{\mm\per\second}  & 749.88 &  0.164 & 207.7   & 254.8 & 570 & 0.699 & 94.45\\
    
    0.18\;\si{\mm\per\second}   & 751.4 & 0.048 &   239.3 & 172.0 &     590  &0.531 & 95.84\\
    
    0.16\;\si{\mm\per\second} &  760.1 & 0.058 & 113.8 & 189.2 & 511  & 0.643 &  94.97\\
    
    0.14\;\si{\mm\per\second} & 760.9 &  0.004 & 395.2 & 295.6 &     9720 &  0.055 & 99.65\\
    
    0.13\;\si{\mm\per\second}     & 846.9 &  0.011 & 153.4 & 119.2 & 2970 &  0.153 & 99.04\\
    
    0.12\;\si{\mm\per\second} & 826.4     & 0.066 &  97.7 &  277.6 & 609.1 & 0.922 & 94.28\\
    
    0.1\;\si{\mm\per\second} &   725.4 &     0.002 & 126.6 & 120.4 & 7580.0 & 0.0279 &   99.82 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `p` instead of `m` in your column definitions and that will give you what you expect. (`p` will align on the first line, `m` will align centered and `b` will align on the bottoms).